# Laravel 4 many 2 many change record.id to something else

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, many-to-many

Im using a pivot table. I have a model Category and a model for Product.

```
<?php

class Product extends \Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'products';

    public function categories(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('Product', 'category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id');
    }
}


<?php

class Category extends \Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'categories';

    public function products(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('Category', 'category_product', 'product_id', 'category_id');
    }

}
```

When i use:

```
$products = Product::with('categories')->get();
```

And dump the query, i get the query below:

```
"select `categories`.*, `category_product`.`category_id` as `pivot_category_id`, `category_product`.`product_id` as `pivot_product_id` from `categories` inner join `category_product` on `categories`.`id` = `category_product`.`product_id` where `category_product`.`category_id` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
```

As you can see, the innerJoin will be done with the product_id and category_id. Is it possible to set those to internal_id for both or do i need to create a custom query?

Comment: What do you mean by "set those to internal_id"? Could you describe more what behavior you're looking for?

Comment: The query looks a bit strange to me as it fetches from the `category` table, joins the `category_product` pivot table and then filters on the `category_id` in the pivot table. But that id is of course already present in the `category` without the join. Is that really the query larval generates?